# Download all artifacts from a nexus Repository

Tags: nexus, nexus3, artifacts

As I don't have Nexus Pro, I can't download all artifacts out of the box.

Any of you know a process or script to download all artifacts from a repository, to import in another instance?

Thanks a lot.

I tried a few scripts but I can't figured it out how to put them working properly

Comment: [Nexus has an API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api)

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. I know that perfectly but I am not able to use it. That’s why I put my question here. Are you able to help?

Comment: How would you not be able to use the API? It is available to anyone. List the artifacts in the repository you want to target, loop on that list to download them and loop on the downloaded files to upload them to the new repo.